# "A mismatch between the PNP/INF version and the KMD file version on the graphics adapter has been detected"

Tags: windbg, wdk, wdf, umdf, iddcx

I've been testing a UMDF IddCx video driver, and this message just started appearing (after devcon.exe install ...) along with a breakpoint in WinDbg:

```
(DriverEntry and EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD handlers succeed as they did prior to this error message)
    .
    .
    .
<==CDriver::OnWdfDriverDeviceAdd [status: STATUS_SUCCESS]

A mismatch between the PNP/INF version and the KMD file version on the graphics adapter has been detected. The adapter will fail to start.
(WinDbg breaks here -- see stack below)

==>CAdapter::OnWdfDeviceD0Entry(hWdfDevice: <hWdfAdapterDevice>, previousState: 5)
    .
    .
    .
```

**Stack info** (Windows 10 Pro | Test Mode | Build 19041.vb_release.191206-1406):

```
[0x0]   dxgkrnl!DpiFdoValidateKmdAndPnpVersionMatch + 0x88e5c   
[0x1]   dxgkrnl!DpiFdoInitializeFdo + 0x313   
[0x2]   dxgkrnl!DpiAddDevice + 0x1942   
[0x3]   nt!PpvUtilCallAddDevice + 0x3b   
[0x4]   nt!PnpCallAddDevice + 0x94   
[0x5]   nt!PipCallDriverAddDevice + 0x827   
[0x6]   nt!PipProcessDevNodeTree + 0x333   
[0x7]   nt!PiRestartDevice + 0xba   
[0x8]   nt!PnpDeviceActionWorker + 0x46a   
[0x9]   nt!ExpWorkerThread + 0x105   
[0xa]   nt!PspSystemThreadStartup + 0x55   
[0xb]   nt!KiStartSystemThread + 0x28
```

I don't understand what this means; I haven't changed anything in the INF, and this is a UMDF driver, so what "KMD file version" is it referring to? I searched for the message itself and also DpiFdoValidateKmdAndPnpVersionMatch, but came up empty.

**EDIT:** (adding version info)

```
Windows Version Info:
---------------------
Edition ....... Windows 10 Pro
Version ....... 20H2
Installed on .. 1/5/2021
OS build ...... 19042.685
Experience .... Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: the very large offset  0x88e5c usually denotes it is not a valid symbol add windows os version in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Symbol Doesn't Exist in 1909 so that symbol must be a new addition to  20H2
anyway the string in question does exist in 1909

the Failure is supposedly propagated after IoQueryFullDriverPath() and GetFileVersion()
the int3 is Hardcoded after the DebugPrintEx()
the function in question ADAPTER_RENDER::Initialize() is doing a lot of comparisons with hardcoded DWORDS like 'QCOM'  etc

```
C:\> radare2 -Q -qq -c "fs strings;f~mismatch" c:\Windows\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys

0x1c0076940 139 str.A_mismatch_between_the_PNP_INF_version_and_the_KMD_file_version_on_the_graphics_adapter_has_been_detected._The_adapter_will_fail_to_start.


C:\> radare2 -A -Q -qq -c "axt 0x1c0076940" c:\Windows\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
fcn.1c015be84 0x1c0181f01 [DATA] lea r8, str.A_mismatch_between_the_PNP_INF_version_and_the_KMD_file_version_on_the_graphics_adapter_has_been_detected._The_adapter_will_fail_to_start.
```

i was just googling around look for something related to inf and GetKmdFileVersion and it seems you need to provide a specific Version String
[see if you comply with this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/wddm-2-1-features#driver-versioning)

specifically quoting from the doc

> Drivers will report WDDM 2.1 support through
> DXGK_DRIVERCAPS::WDDMVersion with a new version constant:
> DXGK_WDDMVERSION::DXGKDDI_WDDMv2_1 = 0x2100 Dxgkrnl will not use the
> WDDMVersion cap as a way to determine which new features are
> supported—that task will be left to other caps or DDI presence.
> However, if the driver reports WDDM 2.1 support through the
> WDDMVersion cap, dxgkrnl will validate that caps or DDIs required by
> WDDM 2.1 are present and fail to create the adapter if they are not.
> Inconsistent caps will result in failure to create adapter or segment.

Comment: That's some impressive detective work there. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\DisableVersionMismatchCheck = 1 [DWORD Type]